# dynamic arrays and speed in python - fastest way to grow an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've found a few general posts on this question (especially list vs. array), but I wonder if anyone knows if it's faster to use numpy.append, or to reassign entries?

Specifically, if you knew you were to have an array of max size 100, say, but weren't sure of the final size, would it be better to:

```
array_to_mod = np.zeros(100)
for something in loop:
    array_to_mod[something] = new_value
final_array = array_to_mod[0:len(loop)]
```

where loop is some number that you don't know a priori except that it's below 100, or instead something like:

```
final_array = np.array([])
for something in loop:
    final_array = np.append(final_array, new_value)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I would go with the first one.

Comment: As @Divakar suggests, I also think that reserving the maximum amount of space (if it is close to the final shape) and then returning a `view` or a `copy` of only the interesting part would be much more efficient than iteratively concatenating existing arrays.

Answer (score 5):

**Perfomance** tests:

```
def func1(new_value):
    array_to_mod = np.zeros(100)
    for i in range(0,100):
        array_to_mod[i] = new_value
    final_array = array_to_mod[0:len(range(0,100))]
    return final_array

def func2(new_value):
    final_array = np.array([])
    for i in range(0,100):
        final_array = np.append(final_array, new_value)
    return(final_array)

In [236]: %timeit func1(1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.5 us per loop

In [237]: %timeit func2(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 789 us per loop
```

So firs method is much faster you should use that as @Divakar mentioned in the comment

Answer (score 2):

`np.append` is clearly a bad choice for repeated use.  It is just a cover for `np.concatenate`.  In this context it is effectively:

```
final_array = np.concatenate(final_array, [new_value])
```

It makes a new array with one new value.  Making a new array each iteration is the big time consumer (not so much the copying).

But list append is a good choice -

```
def func3(new_value):
    alist=[]
    for i in range(0,100):
        alist.append(new_value)
    return np.array(alist)
```

In my quick tests it is just as fast as `Anton's` `func1`.

`func3` could be rewritten with a list comprehension with a modest speed increase.

```
 return np.array([new_value for _ in range(0,100)])
```

But here's something that is 2x as fast:

```
def func4(new_value):
    return np.fromiter([new_value for _ in range(0,100)], int, count=100)
```

The expression for `fromiter` could be a generator, though in this case it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that for numpy arrays, case 1 should generally be faster, but timing it is the right way to go.

Similarly for matrices, if you want to append a column of 1 (or 0), copying an array is faster than the internal hstack method.

```
temp = np.copy(X)
X = np.ones([m,n+1])
X[:,1:] = temp
del temp
```

executes faster than

```
X = np.hstack( [np.ones([m, 1]), X] )
```

In many scenarios, the latter could still be preferrable because of its brevity and even for readability.

If you know how many element are appended in the end, you might be able to collect them and stack arrays together:

```
array_to_mod = np.zeros(100)
def stack(old, new):
    out = np.ones(len(old)+len(new))
    out[0:len(old)] = old
    out[len(old):] = new
    return out
```

Answer (score 1):

according to [numpy.append documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html),

> Values are appended to a copy of this array.

So the second method have a O (n²) complexity, while the first is O(n).

Another point : numpy.array individual access is slow, so you will be faster on python lists. The best way here is probably :

```
final_list = []
for something in loop:
    final_list.append(new_value)
final_array=np.array(final_list)
```

Finally, numpy 1D array are designed for vectorization, so must not be managed with for loop. It depends of specific problem to achive this goal.